# how can i make UNNotificationRequest to be multiple requests in queue

Tags: xcode, ios11, swift4

```
    let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: notificationtime, repeats: false)
    // Create Notification Request
    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "cocoacasts_local_notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)  
        }
    }
```

Now is no request can make in Queue, only one request can make,
the new request will eat the old request

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask

Comment: only one request can make in future notification

i want more than one request  in future notification,Sorry my english is bad